# Using Latex in my plots is causing a misalignment of the legend labels and the y-tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I want to use Latex syntax in my python plots, to be able to use the SI units package in the title or for other labels. Here is a minimal example of the code I'm using:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib as mpl


mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{siunitx}'

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize']  = 14
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize']  = 15
mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize']  = 15
mpl.rcParams['axes.labelsize']   = 18
mpl.rcParams['figure.titlesize'] = 18
DOTSIZE    =  3.5

X = np.linspace(0.001,1,1000)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,6))
plt.plot(X, X, label = 'data')
plt.title(r'using SI Units like $\SI{100}{\hertz}$', fontsize = 20)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.grid(color = 'grey', which = 'both', alpha = 0.4, linestyle = '--', linewidth = 1)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
plt.show()
```

This generates the following plot:

[image: Python Plot]

The legend labels are misaligned and the labels for the y-ticks are not aligned with the correct tick for the log scale.

I tried to find the cause for that and it looks like that the misalignment is caused by the line:

```
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

Commenting that part out, results in a plot, where everything is aligned as I wish, but without that I also can't use the SI units anymore.
Does anybody know why this misalignment is caused and how I can solve it?
There seem to be a lot of other ways to implement Latex syntax in python plots, but none where I could successfully use SI Units in the labels.

Comment: Works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcZ3k.jpg Can you check that all your tools are up-to-date?

Comment: After updating anaconda, it also works fine for me now, thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz !

Comment: Great to hear you could solve the problem!